# There exists matching of size at least $E(G)/\Delta(G)$ for bipartite graph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, induction, discrete-geometry, matching-theory

To show: There exists a matching of size at least $|E(G)|/\Delta(G)$ for any bipartite graph $G$. ($\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree)

Approach. : If say $|E(G)|/\Delta(G)= k+\epsilon, 0\le\epsilon<1 $ So we need to prove there exists a matching of size at least k. (Since size of matching is an integer).

I was trying induction on $[|E(G)|/\Delta(G)]$ ($[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function). For base case 1, we can just take an edge between the vertex with highest degree and one of its neighbours to get a matching of size 1.

Induction hypothesis: this is true for all $k'<k$. To prove that this is true for $k$.

Proof: This is where I am not able to move further.

My attempt: I'm trying to extend the matching when $k$ increases. Comparing to when $k'=k-1$, we now have $\Delta(G)$ more edges to choose from i.e. $2\Delta(G)$ total vertices to choose from. $2k'(<2(k-1))$ vertices are chosen in the matching of size $k'$ so we can pick two vertices not already present in that matching.

Problem: What if all the $2\Delta(G)$ vertices to choose from are already chosen in the previous matching? I know we don't really have to extend the matching. I am also open to any new way of proving this.

Comment: [This question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3716585/177399) outlines a potential solution. However, to be complete, you need to prove that $G$ has a matching which covers all vertices in $G$ with degree $\Delta(G)$. I do not know if this is indeed true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use Koning's theorem to conclude that the maximum size of the matching in a bipartite graph is equal to the minimum size of the vertex cover. Let $\beta(G)$ be the size of the min vertex cover.

The inequality you want to prove becomes
$$
\beta(G) \Delta(G) \geq E(G).
$$
Can you finish it now?

Comment: Yes, I was able to. Thanks!

Comment: @greg If you find an answer helpful, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark. This signals to everyone your issue has been resolved (and awards the answerer (and you) some points).